# dynamically catch exceptions in TensorFlow as part of the graph execution

Tags: tensorflow

E.g. the `QueueBase.dequeue` function can raise an `OutOfRangeError` exception which I will receive in Python from the `Session.run` call. Is there any way I can catch the exception inside the graph, similar as `tf.cond`? E.g. something like:

```
result = tf.on_exception(queue.dequeue(), lambda: 42)
```

Maybe also the first argument would need to be a `lambda` such that it can properly set the context.
To make this work, like in `tf.cond`, the result from both arguments would need to be of the same type.

Comment: Note that anybody that is interested can follow a longer discussion here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As far as I know, there is no way to handle exceptions in graph, exception handling is done in python. Besides, queue runners run in threads separate from main graph execution anyway.

Comment: But the `dequeue` might be not in a queue runner but in the main computation. I opened an [upstream feature request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10332) about this.